# How to get internal storage size of a windows phone 8 device programmatically

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'm creating a windows phone 8 app and I need to get internal storage size of the device. I'm using C# in building my app.

Comment: What would you do with the answer?  Your app cannot determine whether user is running some other app which is competing for available memory.  Or if your app starts first and hogs most of avail memory, then user decides to start some other app, it might yield laggy performance in either app, or both.

Comment: i need yo calculate the device internal storage !

Answer (score 0):

From here:
[How much storage do I have access to on WP7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774783/how-much-storage-do-i-have-access-to-on-wp7)

You can test for available space with IsolatedStorageFile.AvailableFreeSpace.

You should be careful about using all available space as it will impact other apps and general device performance. Hopefully the OS will stop anything horrible happening if you did use all free space but best to try and avoid being the cause of this.

There are some limits on the number of fies and directories you can have but you're very unlikely to hit these. Details at http://dotnetcatch.wordpress.com/2010/09/08/wp7-how-many-files-does-it-take-to-crash-isolatedstorage-more-than-you-think/

Comment: i'm just want to get phone internal storage and total available storage 
EX:
a method return 
Total Storage : 14.2 GB
Free Space : 1.3 GB